# Asking questions for self-benefit

Tags: discussion, badges

One of the badges Tumbleweed is earned if it has low views, no score, etc. for a week. Maybe it is just me, but it might actually encourage some so-called "badge-hunters/achievers/perfectionists" to ask questions like "this question is just to earn badge, please don't answer/score me" etc. So how are the questions that are asked just for the personal achievement sake, dealt with?

Comment: I can assure you that such a question would get downvoted to oblivion and closed very fast... unless maybe it is tagged with the most obscure tags that no-one even follows. So, they are dealt with by the community, like any other questions not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: to follow up on @Tunaki's comment, I can assure you based on past experience, such a question would be downvoted to oblivion. I've actually seen questions that actually state they are trying to get tumbleweed badge

Comment: @psubsee2003 Then, how exactly can you get such unpopular question through the legal means?

Comment: You don't ask a question to get the badge. You get the badge as compensation of having the really unfortunate event that no-one commented / voted on your question for a whole week.

Comment: @Tunaki Sorry, I haven't realized my "badge-collectivism" suddenly played up =P

Comment: @Tunaki Also, what if it is a question, where upvotesCount === downvotesCount? Will it be considered a no score? I'm asking that since I happen to have [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823291/dynamically-modify-value-of-html-htmlhelper), which by circumstances was left alone. So I thought, at least I could try to get a badge compensation out of it.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok from personal experience, you get the badge from asking a question that absolutely no one cares about.  If you ask a bad question, you won't get the badge  Don't try to get it.  It just happens.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I won't, in fact, I was not trying to get that badge, at the time I was more worried noone would help with it, and I don't have a priviledge to assign bounties to bump it up.

Comment: Hard to get the point, 98% of all questions here are asked for the OP's personal benefit.  That such a question might be beneficial to other programmers is assumed.  But not always accomplished, the "debug my code" and "do my homework" questions are invariably poorly received.

Comment: With how huge Stack Overflow is nowadays, I can't imagine it's actually that hard to ask a legitimate question that goes completely ignored for a week. My first question earned me a Tumbleweed badge (it was about an obscure problem with JDB, a horrible tool that no one uses, so that probably helped).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does encourage badge hunters.  I've actually seen questions that say "don't answer this, I am trying to get a tumbleweed badge". And those questions are quickly downvoted, closed, and deleted, and the user's badge hunt results in nothing.

The advantage here is the community is active enough the such questions are always downvoted and deleted, and the user does not get the badge.  The only way to get the badge is to ask a legitimate question that absolutely no one cares about.  If the question if bad enough or good enough, enough people will look at it and the badge won't be awarded.